# apt-get error: "SysV: not found"

Tags: apt, dpkg, systemd, sysv

On a Ubuntu 14.04 system we had installed `elasticsearch 2.3.4`.

The system was upgraded to 16.04

An `apt-get update` & `upgrade` tried to upgrade to `elasticsearch 2.4.4`.

But, we're now getting this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried:

- `apt-get install -f`

  ```
  dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--configure):
   package elasticsearch is not ready for configuration
   cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
  Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   elasticsearch
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
  ```
- `dpkg --configure -a`

  ```
  no output
  ```
- `apt-get install --reinstall elasticsearch`

  ```
  Preparing to unpack .../elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb ...
  /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
  dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb (--unpack):
   subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 127
  /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
  dpkg: error while cleaning up:
   subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   /var/cache/apt/archives/elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
  ```
- `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq elasticsearch`

  ```
  dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
  dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
   reinstall it before attempting a removal
  (Reading database ... 157552 files and directories currently installed.)
  Removing elasticsearch (2.3.4) ...
  /var/lib/dpkg/info/elasticsearch.postrm: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
  dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--remove):
   subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   elasticsearch
  ```
- `dpkg --remove --force-all elasticsearch`

  ```
  elasticsearch
  dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
  dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
   reinstall it before attempting a removal
  (Reading database ... 157552 files and directories currently installed.)
  Removing elasticsearch (2.3.4) ...
  /var/lib/dpkg/info/elasticsearch.postrm: 43: /etc/default/elasticsearch: SysV: not found
  dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--remove):
   subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   elasticsearch
  ```
- `dpkg --purge elasticsearch`

  ```
  dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--purge):
   package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
   reinstall it before attempting a removal
  Errors were encountered while processing:
   elasticsearch
  ```

I've even tried switching back from systemd to upstart-sysv, but after a reboot nothing has changed.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/8 ?

Comment: I have no trouble starting or stopping the service using "service elasticsearch stop" , but this pointed me towards the /etc/default/elasticsearch file, that contained the SysV config. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /etc/default/elasticsearch there is a section

```
SysV init.d
# When executing the init script, this user will be used to run the elasticsearch service.
# The default value is 'elasticsearch' and is declared in the init.d file.
# Note that this setting is only used by the init script. If changed, make sure that
# the configured user can read and write into the data, work, plugins and log directories.
# For systemd service, the user is usually configured in file /usr/lib  /systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
ES_USER=elasticsearch
ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
```

I commented the entire section.

The installation was then able to proceed.

It actually prompted me with the "Install package maintainer version / Keep system version" question, which in the diff showed that the intention of the installation is to comment out that section anyways.